# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<SelectOption<Integer>> to List<SelectOption<String>>?

Tags: java, string, generics, collections, integer

Here's code:

```
List<SelectOption<String>> validMemberList = ValidDataUtil.getValidMemberType();
```

Can anyone tell me :

How can convert the `List<SelectOption<Integer>>` to `List<SelectOption<String>>` ?

Comment: Please append the `SelectOption` API.

Comment: create the List<SelectOption<String>> first, then convert and add the SelectOption<Integer>s one by one?  The point is we (and the compiler) don't obviously see how to convert a SelectOption<Integer> to a SelectOption<String>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can convert the `List<SelectOption<Integer>>` to `List<SelectOption<String>>` ?

You can't, directly. You can loop through the first and use `toString` on each of the integers to build the second, though.

Answer (score 1):

> How can convert the `List<SelectOption<Integer>> to
>   List<SelectOption<String>>` ?

You can't, because both are two different data types. Iterate the list and convert each element with `toString()` method.